# Mapping list of objects to a list of strings

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

```
class ContactDTO(
        var isEmergency: Boolean? = null, 
        var phones: MutableList<ContactIn>? = null) : 
Parcelable {
...}
```

I am trying to map the above to a list of string phone numbers
(ContactIn has a isPrimary field)

I have the following but it is asking for a boolean predicate?

```
var contacts = contactsDTO?.contacts?.filter { contactDTO -> contactDTO.isEmergency == true }
contacts.map { contactDTO -> contactDTO.phones.filter { phone -> phone.isPrimary } }
```

thanks.

Comment: Well, first thing is it seems like you're returning an optional from the first statement.  So, contacts?.map{...}

Comment: @Beto show more ContactIn and complete ContactDTO class pls

Answer (score 0):

`isEmergency` is a `String?` you cannot compare it to `true`. You should definitely rename that property, because `is...` is the convention for Booleans.

Comment: thanks for that, mistake from copy and pasta. Updated question.

Comment: @Beto so where exaclty is the problem now? your code looks good :) as far as I can tell

Comment: well, the final result should be a list<String> of phone numbers but map is not even compilint it. it says it expected a boolean for the 2nd line

Answer (score 0):

`map` is used to transform each element to some other and **not** to make `key-value` pairs.
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html.

Use `associate` or any other variant such as `associateWith`, `associateBy`, `associateTo`, or `associateByTo` to achieve the desired result.